# getting result of data between 2 dates in cake 3 php

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to make search form using cake3 , to get the values between 2 dates . But I'm getting error , and don't know why .

Here's my form :

```
 <?php echo $this->Form->create('CustodyKeys', array('type' => 'get',
                    'url'   => array(
                     'controller' => 'CustodyKeys','action' => 'resultypeLongTerm'
                  )));?>                                      
        <div class="row">                                  
                        <div class="form-group col-md-12">                                                                          
                           <?php
                          echo $this->Form->input('keys_custody_status_name', ['placeholder'=>__('Enter Custody statue'),'class' => 'form-control','label'=>__('Custody statue')]);
                        ?>                                                                                                          
                        </div>
        </div>                                                                                                                 
        <div class="row">                                                                             
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
             <?php 
                               echo $this->Form->input('received_date_from', ['type' => 'text', 'placeholder' => __('Received Date From'), 'label' => __('Received Date From'), 'class' => 'form-control hasGorgianDatePicker','value'=>'from']);
                            ?>                                                  
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <?php 
                               echo $this->Form->input('received_date_to', ['type' => 'text', 'placeholder' => __('Received Date to'), 'label' => __('Received Date to'), 'class' => 'form-control hasGorgianDatePicker']);
                            ?>                                                                          
                        </div>
```

And here's my function at the controller :

```
 $date_start = 'received_date_from';
        $date_end = 'received_date_to';

   $conditions = $this->CustodyKeys->find(
          'all',array('conditions'=>array('CustodyKeys.received_date_from >=' => array($date_start), 
    'CustodyKeys.received_date_to <=' => array($date_end)))
          )  ;
 $this->set('data', $conditions);
```

and here's the ctp to show the result of the search :

```
<?php foreach ($data as $custodyKey): ?>
                                    <tr>

                                      <td><?= $custodyKey->id ?></td>
```

The debug giving me that result :

> '(help)' => 'This is a Query object, to get the results execute or iterate it.',
>       'sql' => 'SELECT CustodyKeys.id AS `CustodyKeys__id`, CustodyKeys.holders_keys_id AS `CustodyKeys__holders_keys_id`, CustodyKeys.keys_management_id AS `CustodyKeys__keys_management_id`, CustodyKeys.keys_custody_type_id AS `CustodyKeys__keys_custody_type_id`, CustodyKeys.keys_custody_status_id AS `CustodyKeys__keys_custody_status_id`, CustodyKeys.received_date AS `CustodyKeys__received_date`, CustodyKeys.return_date AS `CustodyKeys__return_date`, CustodyKeys.last_status_date AS `CustodyKeys__last_status_date`, CustodyKeys.notes AS `CustodyKeys__notes` FROM custody_keys CustodyKeys WHERE (CustodyKeys.received_date_from >= :c0 AND CustodyKeys.received_date_to <= :c1)',
>       'params' => [
>           ':c0' => [
>               'value' => [
>                   (int) 0 => 'received_date_from'
>               ],
>               'type' => null,
>               'placeholder' => 'c0'
>           ],
>           ':c1' => [
>               'value' => [
>                   (int) 0 => 'received_date_to'
>               ],
>               'type' => null,
>               'placeholder' => 'c1'
>           ]
>       ],

Answer (score 0):

To convert a query object into an array you can work with use:

```
$data->toArray()
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$conditions = $this->CustodyKeys->find('all',
    array('conditions'=>
        array('CustodyKeys.received_date_from >= '. $date_start,
        'CustodyKeys.received_date_to <= '. $date_end))
);
```